# How to download the created PDF file in python?

Tags: python, linux

I am able to convert the HTML to PDF and store it on a local Directory. The point is how do I download the same file after its beeing created progamatically using python?

## This is my code:

```
filename = "test.pdf"
        body= fromstring( u"<div>" + tostring( fromstring(   str(self.request.post['content']).decode('utf-8') ).body ) + u"</div>" )
        tx = tostring(body).encode('utf-8')
        pisa.CreatePDF(tx, file(filename, 'wb'))
```

Comment: Did you notice that there is an explicit link in the Django documentation index for [Generating PDF](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/outputting-pdf/)?

Comment: You have created a file and you want to download it. That's pretty vague. Uh... use `scp`? Download to where?

Comment: Celada,I want to download it thru the box( that asks you when u download something like zip file, Open and Save as)? I know its vague  a bit...!

Comment: Daniel, I ok with generating the file, the point is how can I open the generated file immediately?

Comment: please update your post to provide some more info: Are you working on a web-service? Which framework?

Comment: I am working with Werkzeug and Jinja2? I want to open the created pdf file, but to appear the dialog box for openning or saving the file? I think that I need to use Content-type header:...!

Answer (score 0):

Hi there I founded the solution:

```
    fh = open('path_to_file','r')
    self._response.data = fh.read()
    fh.close() 

    self._response.headers.add('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
    self._response.headers.add('Content-Disposition', 'attachment')
```

So now I am able to download the created file...